# Procmail match 4 numbers only in email address

Tags: regex, numbers, match, digits, procmail

How can I make Procmail match an email address which always has 4 numbers in it?

e.g.

```
1234@mydomain.com
```

I have read that procmail does not support the modern extended regular expression implementations of repetition, such as

```
^To:.[0123456789]{4}@mydomain.com$
```

So how else would I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot use *limiting quantifiers*, just repeat the pattern:

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]@mydomain[.]com
```

This will match 4 digits followed by `@domain.com`. Note that the `.` must be either escaped or put into a character class to match a literal dot (a `.` matches any character but a newline).

To match a string that starts with `To:`, followed with any character but a newline and followed with the 4-digit username email, use

```
^To:.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]@mydomain[.]com
```

See more details on [Procmail regex here](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~ian/procmail.html#regexps).